# Generate 4 random number whose sum is 100 and one is more than 50

Tags: c#

I need to create 4 int random numbers whose sum is 100. And one of them is more than 50 and bigger than the others.
I have this:

```
int a=0, b=0,c=0,d=0;
int cem=100;
while (a+b+c+d=cem){
Random perc = new Random();
a = perc.Next(50, 100);
b = perc.Next(0, 50);
c = perc.Next(0, 50);
d = perc.Next(0, 50);
}
```

in the compiler i get 2 errors:

The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property of indexer
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: Changing `a+b+c+d=cem` to `a+b+c+d==cem` will solve the compiler error. As it currently stands, I can't see how the content of your `while` loop will ever run though.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
while (a+b+c+d=cem){
```

with

```
while (a+b+c+d!=cem){
```

You're using assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`/`!=`).

Comment: Actually it should be !=, else it'll be false and the loop will not run.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers regarding the compiler error message, you should also move the line

```
Random perc = new Random();
```

to the outside of the `while` loop. You don't need more than a single random number generator, and recreating it in a quick loop may produce identical results due to the time seed.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, four random numbers with sum 100 means that only three of them are random and the fourth is 100 minus the other three... so instead of doing a loop first generate one number, then generate another one with the remaining interval and then a third one.

Answer (score 1):

why using a loop? good luck with getting what you want :-)

(so much cpu wasted)

here is how i would start doing it;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
        int cem = 100;
        Random perc = new Random();

        a = perc.Next(50, cem);
        cem -= a;

        b = perc.Next(0, cem);
        cem -= b;

        c = perc.Next(0, cem);
        cem -= c;

        d = cem;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} + {2} + {3} = {4}",a,b,c,d,a+b+c+d);

        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
```

The while wants ==, assuming C# is like C. == is equality test, = is assignment.

(It should be obvious why this causes the first error message. You may need to think about why it explains the second, but since doing so is a good exercise I'm not going to explain.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, will less number of loops ?

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
int cem = 100;
Random perc = new Random();
a = perc.Next(50, cem);
b = perc.Next(0, cem - a);
c = perc.Next(0, cem - a - b);
d = cem - a - b - c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program {
    void Main() {
        var random = new Random();

        // note it says one of them is more than 50
        // so the min value should be 51 not 50
        var a = random.Next(51, 100);

        // the rest of the number will be less than `a` 
        // because `a` is more than 50 so the max `remaining` 
        // will be is 49 (100 - 51)
        var remaining = 100 - a; 

        var b = random.Next(0, remaining);
        remaining -= b;

        var c = random.Next(0, remaining);
        remaining -= c;

        var d = remaining;

        Console.WriteLine("a: " + a);
        Console.WriteLine("b: " + b);
        Console.WriteLine("c: " + c);
        Console.WriteLine("d: " + d);
        Console.WriteLine("total: " + (a + b + c + d));
    }
}
```